# How can I create a repeating onClick animation for an ImageView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The code I have below animates an ImageView the way it is supposed to. The problem is that it does not repeat. (emoji is an ImageView)

What it currently does: the emoji is visible on the screen when the activity starts. It slides up when the screen is clicked, then it disappears(as it should).

Problem 1: I don't want the emoji to be visible when the activity starts.

Problem 2: The onClick only works one time. After that first click, the emoji won't show up again.

```
ConstraintLayout mLayout = findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout);
    mLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            emojiPopup();
        }
    });

public void emojiPopup() {
    final ImageView emojiFace = findViewById(R.id.face);
    emojiFace.animate().translationY(-200).alpha(1.0f).setDuration(500).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            emojiFace.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
    });
}
```

The `public void onClick(View view) {emojiPopup();}` should happen every time I click the screen, why does it only work on the first click?

Maybe I am taking the wrong approach or I'm not seeing something obvious, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1**

Set your `ImageView` to INVISIBLE in your `OnCreate()` method.

**Problem 2**

After the first animation ends, you set its visibility to GONE, and you never set it to VISIBLE after that, that's why you can never see it after the first animation. So at the start of your `emojiPopup()` method, set it to VISIBLE first, then animate and hide it.